# Extract most recent N dates from date column with duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data table in a SQL Server database with date columns like below. There are many duplicates in date column.

```
    date
0   2018-08
1   2018-09
2   2018-09
3   2018-09
4   2018-10
5   2018-09
6   2018-08
7   2018-07
...........
```

I need to extract the most recent two dates (or more) from the column. 
The following SQL code works:

```
SELECT TOP 2 date 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM myTbl) t
ORDER BY date DESC
```

However, I feel there must be a better way to do this. Does anyone know a better/quicker way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 date
FROM myTbl
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (2) date
FROM myTbl
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

I always get the `DISTINCT` and `TOP` confused, so you can also write:

```
SELECT TOP (2) date
FROM myTbl
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an another option you can use the [SQL Server OFFSET FETCH](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-offset-fetch/).

The `OFFSET` and `FETCH` clauses are the options of the `ORDER BY` clause. They allow you to limit the number of rows to be returned by a query.

```
create table MyTable (Id int, dtDate Varchar(10))
Insert into MyTable Values
(0, '2018-08'),
(1, '2018-09'),
(2, '2018-09'),
(3, '2018-09'),
(4, '2018-10'),
(5, '2018-09'),
(6, '2018-08'),
(7, '2018-07)')

SELECT
   Distinct dtDate
FROM
    MyTable
ORDER BY
    dtDate desc 
OFFSET 0 ROWS 
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

The output is shown below.

```
 dtDate
--------
2018-10
2018-09
```

[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ab3fe57756b45d868b3882304fafc25a)

Answer (score 0):

Sample data,

```
create table #MyTable (Id int, dtDate Varchar(10))
Insert into #MyTable Values
(0, '2018-08'),
(1, '2018-09'),
(2, '2018-09'),
(3, '2018-09'),
(4, '2018-10'),
(5, '2018-09'),
(6, '2018-08'),
(7, '2018-07')
```

you can avoid `DISTINCT` especially where there is lot of data involve and it is use in complex query.

Most importantly you are storing data in wrong manner.Store data with suitable data type.

As you can yourself see there is no ease in fetching data for desire output.

NO matter how you want to display.It is easy and reliable to do manipulation on approriate data type.

```
 ;With CTE as
(
 select *
,dateadd(second,id,(concat(dtDate,'-01') ))dtDate1 
from #MyTable
)
,CTE1 as
(
 select dtDate,MAX(dtDate1)as dtDate1
from cte
group by dtDate
)

select top 2 * from cte1
order by dtDate1 desc

　 
drop table #MyTable
```

`Order` on `varchar` is also dangerous.Tomorrow you may need to do some calculation on `dtDate`.

Comment: Grouping without an aggregate is the same as DISTINCT. If unique values are needed, the usage of DISTINCT much more clearly expresses the goal to anyone reading the code. The optimizer will likely use the same execution plan for either approach.